# How to rewrite rule with optional pagination

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

How do i rewrite a rule with optional pagination?

I have the following url:

```
http://www.example.com/discography/year/?year=1985
```

optionally, the url can contain pagination, like this:

```
// the digits after year = page #
http://www.example.com/discography/year/3/?year=1985
```

I've created the following rule (an a bunch of similar ones), with no success. I'm going crazy trying to figure this one out.

```
RewriteRule ^discography/year/(\d+)\?year=(\d+)$ music/music.php?p=$1&year=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^discography/year/?$  music/music.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^discography/year/(\d+)/?$ music/music.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```

P.S: `QSA`  flag adds current query string to the one mentioned in your rewrite rule, so you  don't need `&year=$2` in your rewrite rule.